# Why can't I use a fstream vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, fstream

When I try to use a `vector <fstream>`, it outputs a compile error. Why does C++ forbid a vector of fstream?

Comment: A possible (not necessarily sensible) workaround on a non-C++11 compiler is to use a `std::vector <std::fstream*>` ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because fstream is not copyable

Comment: Technically, `fstream` is only "moveable" in C++11, as the concept didn't exist in C++03. And in C++11, you can put moveable-only types in a C++11 `std::vector`. So his code would compile on a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Honestly, I have to say [this piece](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Ftdq5%246) is the biggest error to code ratio I've ever seen. Shouldn't this work, or am I being silly about some move semantics thing?

Comment: @chris:  The error is due to GCC attempting to use move_if_noexcept (or something based on it) in it's implementation of emplace_back (in the case where the vector has to grow, which has to compile even in the case where it's not used at runtime).  However, fstream's move constructor isn't marked as 'noexcept', requiring it to fall back on the copying version.

Comment: @DaveS, Ah, I see. A bit odd if you ask me, but I'll take it.

Comment: @DaveS: However, `std::vector` will move anyways if there is *only* a move constructor, regardless of `noexcept`-ness.

Comment: @Xeo: That being the difference between what it should do, and [what it does do](http://ideone.com/wlE4kq) in that specific version of the compiler.